# Code works in Windows but not Raspberry pi (opencv)

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm new to coding and using a raspberry pi. I've searched through many tutorials online and found a how to get OpenCV library into the pi itself and downloaded VSC on my laptop and the pi. The issue that I'm having is the code that I used on my laptop doesn't work the same on the pi. I've been getting errors on my code that dosen't show in in my laptop VSC.

the purpose is to display a live feed from the camera in the raspberry pi

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.5,fy=0.5)
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)

    ch = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if ch & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

- (line 10) error: (-206:Bad flag (parameter or structure field)) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function 'cvGetMat'
- (line 9) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Comment: pi camera connected to device ? if not which camera did you plug to raspberry ? This is cos of that device cant reach the camera to stream.

Comment: Are you using a pi camera or a USB web cam? If you are using a pi camera then [read this to make sure you are setting up properly](https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/). If you are using a USB cam then check that the capture number is correct, it maybe `1` rather than `0`. If you are still struggling I suggest asking the same question on the [Raspberry Pi Stack](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use different device id in `cv.VideoCapture(id)`

because raspberry is using linux and at some point the id is not always `0`